# Mouseover Div Dimensions Issue

Tags: css, image, html, mouseover

im currently working on the section of a site in which there is a grid of images.  Im trying to set it up so when you mouse over the image, another div appears with some opaque background and text.  the issue is that I cant get the mouseover div to match the same dimensions of the parent.  as of now, it sticky way out in both directions.  any suggestions?  heres some code

```
<div class = 'picture-container'>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-left'>
                <div class = 'onhover'>hello!</div>
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-right'>
                <div class = 'onhover'>hello!</div>
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-center'>
                <div class = 'onhover'>hello!</div>
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
        </div>

.onhover{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#F5D892;
    opacity:.4;
}


.picture-wrapper{
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
}

.picture-wrapper:hover .onhover{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXudU/1/)

```
<div class='picture-container'>
    <div class='picture-wrapper' id='top-left'>
        <div class='onhover'>hello!</div>
        <div class="img"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class='picture-wrapper' id='top-right'>
        <div class='onhover'>hello!</div>
        <div class="img"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class='picture-wrapper' id='top-center'>
        <div class='onhover'>hello!</div>
        <div class="img"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

.onhover {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#F5D892;
    opacity:.4;
}
.picture-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.picture-wrapper:hover .onhover {
    display:block;
}
.img
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

see what you think